# Java Mail API credentials verification

Tags: java, session, gmail, jakarta-mail, transport

**Question:** Is there any **other** way to verify credentials before sending an email while using Java Mail API?

---

**Introduction:**

My goal is to brake down sending emails into 2 steps:

1. **Sign in** (if username or password doesn't match, a user will get the corresponding message)
2. **Send email**

Currently I'm achieving it from this snippet of code:

```
...
// no Authenticator implementation as a parameter 
Session session = Session.getInstance(Properties props); 
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

transport.connect(username, password);

transport.sendMessage(Message msg, Address[] addresses);
...
```

---

**Conclusion:**
I'm getting my work done just fine, but I'm curious if there are any other ways to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Another way to verify credentials before sending an email

This approach is more convenient than my first one for two reasons:

- We don’t need to keep the **Transport**’s instance alive
- To send emails we can simply use **Transport**’s static method `send(Message msg)`, which we couldn’t use earlier

---

This time we need to pass Authenticator in `getInstance()` method

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(“username”, “password”);
    }
}

/*
 * no need to pass protocol to getTransport()
 * no need to pass username and password to connect() 
 * if credentials were incorrect, you would get a corresponding error
 */
session.getTransport().connect();



// no need to use instance, we simply use static method
Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already got the answer right there in your code.  The connect method does the sign in with your username and password, throwing an exception if it fails, and the sendMessage message sends the message.  Was that really not obvious?

Comment: Thank you Bill, but you can find the answer on your question in my question as well. I just asked about alternative ways of doing so.

Comment: And I see, you’re close to Java Mail API, so I’d like to ask you next, if you don’t mind. Is there any option to still use static Transport.connect() while using approach mentioned in my question without authentication of credentials twice?

Comment: No.  Is there some reason you need to?

Comment: it is. In that case I don’t need to keep Transport’s instance alive and pass it through my methods to do work. But to do verification twice seems overkill. By the way you just answered on my primary question!